# Delete one entry from pivot table laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

How can i delete only one entry from many-to-many relationship pivot table in laravel if i have the id of the row?

I have 2 entities in relation of many to many.
If i have users for example and user_id = 1(2 entries of this user in table) if i do users->entity()->detach() it will delete all the entries with user_id = 1, and i want to delete only the entry where pivot->id = some_id_i_give

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with full details?

Comment: I have 2 entities in relation of many to many. If i have users for example and user_id = 1(2 entries of this user in table) if i do users->entity()->detach() it will delete all the entries with user_id = 1, and i want to delete only the entry where pivot->id = some_id_i_give

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it. I used:

`->wherePivot('id', '=', $pivot_id)->detach()`

and it worked great.

Comment: This is not the best practice I think because laravel has already a method for this.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have `User` & `Entity` models with many-to-many relationship. Then you could use

```
$user->entity()->detach($entityId);
```

That will only delete the row with that `$entityId`

Comment: What if $entityId is in more than 1 entry? I think it would delete all of them

Comment: It will delete the matching ‘$userId’ & ‘$entityId’. I assumed that you loaded the intended ‘$user’ model first.

Comment: I can have $userId & $entityId multiple times...so I can't depend on userId-entityId relation, i need to get the pivot->id so that i can delete only one of the entries

Comment: Same $userId & $entityId pair for multiple times?!! Okay then, the answer is irrelevant!

Comment: It would've worked if the $userId & $entityId pair would have been unique. Thank you for your quick response :)

Answer (score 1):

The best practice you can do it like this,

```
// Detach a single entity from the user...
$entity = Entity::find($your_entity_id);
$user->entities()->detach($entity->id);
```

First, find the entity with your desired id by **Entity** Model,

```
$entity = Entity::find($your_entity_id);
```

After you will get entity, you can pass it into `detach()` method,

```
$user->entities()->detach($entity->id);
```

For more information go through [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: What if entity->id is not in only 1 entry? I can have userId = 1 and entityId = 1 multiple times as different entries. I need to delete only the entry where the pivot->id is what i selected. That's why i used the wherePivot